# abmob has limited advertising with apps from the galaxy store

Tags: android, admob

I don't have a google accont dev account. and all galaxy apps are built independently for the galaxy store. However, from the beginning I was limited and this lasted 1 and a half months. At the same time, because there is no google dev, I cannot confirm app-ads.txt

Please give me advice.

Will Admob restrict apps from the Galaxy Store? Should I have a ch play account?

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Admob console
- Go to `Apps` from side menu
- Click on `view all apps`
- Find your app and click on `Add Store`
  [image]
- Select `Samsung Galaxy Store` and continue, and your problem will be solved in couple of days
  [image]